# How to access user model properties after finding?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to implement a user search function.

I have this for for finding the user. I'm using a post request and taking the search parameter from the post request. That parameter is used to search for the username. However, when I try logging the user, nothing comes up.

```
  router.get('/register', function(req, res) {
    var tester;
    User.find({username : "bob"}, function(err, p){
    if (err) console.log("didn't find bob");
    var lolz = p.username;
    console.log(p);
    tester = p;
    console.log(tester);




});
console.log(tester);
res.render('register', {info : "stuff", testuser : tester});
  });
```

And when I log tester before I render, it works. However, when I access the register page, and try to do console.log(testuser.username) I get undefined. I also get undefined for testuser,username within the posted function and on the register page.

Additionally, when I attempt to log tester.username within the routing, I get undefined.

What is the issue here? Because I would like to pass all the found usernames into rendering a page. Thanks!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`User.find` passes an error and an array of matching documents to the callback, so `p` is not a user object, it's an array of user objects (which could be empty if no users match). So you need to access `p[0]` to get the user object itself.

Your second issue if your use of the `tester` variable is incorrect for node's asynchronous IO. Just move your `res.render` call up inside the `User.find` callback function so the control flow and scope nesting is correct.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Didn't realize I was receiving an array.